# Conditional probability binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

> $X$ is a random variable that follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n, p_1$.

> $Y$ is a random variable that follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n, p_2$.

> I do not know whether the two variables are dependent or not.

How do I find

$$P(X=x|Y=y)=\frac{P(X = x \bigcap Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}$$

We have :
$P(Y=y)= {n \choose y} p^y (1-p)^{n-y}$

But I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If so, $P(X=x|Y=y)=P(X=x)$.

Comment: What does "I am given $P(X\mid Y)$" mean _to you_? Because to most people, it would mean that you are _given_ the values of $P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ for all integers $x$ and $y$ in the range $[0, n]$. So, the rest of your question "How do I find...." is vacuous: _look_ at what has been given to you. As to the question about independence of $X$ and $Y$, just check if the _given_ $P(X\mid Y)$ equals $P(X)$ or not.

Comment: I don't understand how the question is vacuous : I am also given $P(Y)=0.718$, but $P(Y=8)=0.0534$. I'm sorry if my question is not formulated correctly. Thanks for the tip about independence!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not so easy: you need to know joint distribution unless rvs are independent, in which case you can just take the product of distributions. If they are not, it is found by taking marginalizing out the distribution of the second rv:
$$
f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f(y)} = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy}
$$